# Default value for each type in typescript

Tags: typescript

Where can I find the default value of each type in typescript? For example, where is mentioned the default value for `number` type is `null` or `0.`? Or about the `string`?

The default value means the value of a variable that is defined, but not assigned. Like `let a : number;`. This happens a lot in object definitions. For example:

```
 class A{
     let a: number;
     let b: string;
 }
 let obj: A;
```

Therefore, the question is on the values of `a` and `b` for `obj`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The default value of every type is `undefined`

From: [MDN - 'undefined'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)

> A variable that has not been assigned a value is of type undefined.

For example, invoking the following will alert the value 'undefined', even though `greeting` is of type `String`

```
let greeting: string;
alert(greeting);
```

Comment: Is this true for typescript? I mean when typescript compile the code, not assigned any default value?

Comment: @OmG Compile some code and see for yourself. TypeScript is merely a type layer on top of JS, and a transpiler. It does not change the meaning of the code, or introduce any of its own semantics.

Comment: Yes, it's true for typescript. I'll add an example to the answer for you.

Comment: Thankyou @torazaburo for fixing up the hash I made of my original answer.

Answer (score 5):

You have to remember that Typescript transpiles to javascript. In Javascript, the default value of an unassigned variable is `undefined`, as defined [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

For example, the following typescript code:

```
let a: string; console.log(a);
```

will transpile to the following javascript and logs `undefined`.

```
var a; console.log(a);
```

This also applies when you pass parameters to a function or a constructor of a class:

```js
// Typescript
function printStr(str: string) {
    console.log(str);
}

class StrPrinter {
    str: string;
    constructor(str: string) {
        this.str = str;
        console.log(this.str);
    }
}

printStr();
let strPrinter = StrPrinter();
```

In the code example above, typescript will complain that the function and the class constructor is missing a parameter. Nevertheless, it will still transpile to transpile to:

```js
function printStr(str) {
    console.log(str);
}
var StrPrinter = (function () {
    function StrPrinter(str) {
        this.str = str;
        console.log(this.str);
    }
    return StrPrinter;
}());
printStr();
var strPrinter = StrPrinter();
```

You might also want to see how typescript transpiles to javascript [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/).

Comment: In recent versions of typescript I have seen that you can not assign 'unassigned' to a string variable. how can this be ?