# HackerRank Plus Minus problem: Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, for-loop, nan

I am trying to solve the **Plus Minus** problem in HackerRank using Typescript. I am getting NaN as result in first two print statements, however, the last one is working. This is my solution:

```
function plusMinus(arr: number[]): void {
    // Write your code here
    
    let pos: number, neg: number, zero: number = 0; 
    
    for (let i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i]>0){
            pos+=1; 
        }
        else if(arr[i]<0){
            neg+=1;
        }
        else{
            zero+=1; 
        }
    }
    let len: number = arr.length;
    let posRatio = (pos/len).toFixed(6);
    let negRatio = (neg/len).toFixed(6);
    let zeroRatio = (zero/len).toFixed(6); 
    
    console.log(posRatio);
    console.log(negRatio);
    console.log(zeroRatio);
    
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Compiler Message
Wrong Answer

Input (stdout)
6
-4 3 -9 0 4 1

Your Output (stdout)
NaN
NaN
0.166667

Expected Output

0.500000
0.333333
0.166667
```

Can anyone help me out to understand what the problem might have been?

Answer (score 1):

```
let pos: number, neg: number, zero: number = 0;
```

You only defined a default value for `zero` in the above line. In JS (or TS), the default value of any variable is `undefined` unless you explicitly set one.

`undefined + 1` is NaN.

```js
console.log(undefined + 1)
```

[Further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448411/default-value-for-each-type-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1):

Issue is in your value initialization.

```js
let pos: number, neg: number, zero: number = 0;
```

If you would log this you will get

```
pos=undefined
neg=undefined
zero=0
```

and now if you try to add number with undefined it will give you `NaN`

Initialize pos, neg and zero to 0 properly.